# Can the encrypt-and-authenticate method result in secure authenticated encryption if the MAC scheme has unique tags（non-deterministic）？

Tags: encryption, protocol-design, mac

If we use non-deterministic MACs in encrypt-and-authenticate approach， is it secure？

Comment: How would a non-deterministic MAC have unique tags?

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily.  Let $M$ be a secure deterministic MAC like HMAC-SHA256.  Define the randomized MAC $M'_{k, \rho}(m) := M_k(m) \mathbin\| \rho$; that is, $M'$ just appends the randomization to the MAC.  Then encrypt-and-authenticate with $M'$ still leaks message equality, even though the MAC is technically randomized.